# Issue parsing dictionary returned from App Script UrlFetchApp.fetch command

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script, http-headers, http-post

Having issues parsing the dictionary returned from UrlFetchApp.fetch via a simple API call.

Here is the code:

```
var HTTPResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('<myURL>', options);
```

where options includes headers and form data and HTTPResponse is converted into a JSON object like this:

```
var results = JSON.parse(HTTPResponse);
```

HTTPResponse from  returns something like this:

```
{"Category 1": "Value 1", "Category 2": "Value 2", 
"Category 3": "Value 3", "Processing Team": "Processing Team 1”}
```

Then, when I do this: results["Category 1"] I get "undefined" as the value which implies "Category 1" isn't an item in the dictionary.

Something about the object or content type returned by the API call is preventing that dictionary from being parsed. The same dictionary can be parsed in a Python interpreter.

What am I missing? Seems like something obvious.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't parse the the returned `HTTPResponse`

The first thing that you should do, is check the response code for being 200, then get the content as text, then parse the text to JSON.  The `HTTPResponse` isn't actually the returned payload.  The return is retrieved with the `getContentText()` method of the HTTPResponse class.

```
var HTTPResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('<myURL>', options);

if (HTTPResponse.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
  throw new Error("Request Failed: " + HTTPResponse.getContentText());
  return;
}

var results = HTTPResponse.getContentText();

results = JSON.parse(results);
```

The `HTTPResponse` is not JavaScript JSON.  It's an object, and it will evaluate as an object if tested for the datatype with `typeof`, but it doesn't parse correctly.  When you try to parse the HTTPResponse you are trying to parse something that's already an object, and it's not a JavaScript object, it's an Apps Script Class.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Last challenge... Converting the object to text then text to a JSON object (as you suggest) returns this for the value of results: [{Category 2=Category 2, Processing Team=Processing Team 1, Category 1=Category 1, Category 3=Category 3}]. Doing a lookup using results ["Category 1"] returns null (presumably, because the colons have been replaced by equal signs?). Again, I know this should be obvious. How do I parse the returned dictionary wrapped in both curly braces and brackets where keys and values are separated by equal signs? Good karma for helping an amateur :).

Comment: Try `results[0]["Category 1"]` because it looks like the object is wrapped in an array.  There are brackets on the outside, indicating that the outer object is an array.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Interestingly, I tried that previously when I was parsing the output from the UrlFetchApp.fetch call which, as you pointed out, was returning an object that couldn't be parsed. Working now. Many thanks.